# FMod Studio is about to arrive, what do you think about it?

Tags: fmod, gameaudio, middleware

FMod guys has redesigned their website, and it seems FMod Studio is just around the corner. They already moved "Designer" and "EX" to their "Legacy" section. And there's a PDF about new FMod features.

Right now I'm working with FMod on a project. And it seems it's not going to be hard to move whole project to Studio from Designer.

So, what do you think about new FMod? Is it really going to be a game changer? Or do you think WWise/another middleware will still be better?

Answer (score 1):

It seems exciting! Actually, the mixing content introduced now, is what I've been missing with FMod Designer. 
Any ideas if it still going to be compatible with FMOD Sandbox?

Comment: http://gameaudiomix.tumblr.com/post/24690306911/a-closer-look-at-fmod-studio